# Close votes: 2 + 2 + 1 - Which one wins?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Just out of curiosity, when a question gets closed with 2 votes for one reason, 2 for another and 1 vote for something else, how is the final close reason determined? Possible methods I can think of are:

- Based on the first vote cast for one of the two vote close reasons
- Selected alphabetically
- Based on the order they are listed as close reasons in the pop-up
- Toss of an electronic coin
- Based on the most commonly used of the two possible reasons

Or it might be something else I haven't considered.

Comment: If a mod casts the last vote then whatever they choose.

Comment: And if a mere mortal casts it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Iain points out, Mods can hammer the Question as they see fit.
If the pair of 2s were Migrate, but to different sites, then it will be closed Off-Topic.
Otherwise the first vote out of all five will be the close reason.

Comment: I assume then if the first vote was the odd one then the next vote would apply.